Turning headings 1 into "Chapter <N>" in officedown::rdocx_document
With bookdown, I can add this in the YAML header:
language:
  ui:
    chapter_name: "Chapter "

Can I do something similar with officedown::rdocx_document for adding this to headings 1?

you need to set up the Word template according to your need and reuse the template with officedown
